# How to build in Magento select attribute with image?

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, image, select

Is there any possible way to create select attribute with image?
For example dropdown list: NEW/SALE/FAV/RATED ... etc and each option with it's own image ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No either you use `swatches` or you use `Drop down`.There is no option of using drop-down with images.If you select drop-down then on back-end you won't be able to upload images. There are extensions that enable you to upload images with options and you can use them. Here is the one i found for you. [SWMS - Option Image2](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/swms-option-image2.html)

Comment: Thank you Shahzaib. I have already one I created but was just curious if there is an option in backed which allow you to do this. Just started playing with backend recently nad found that many things can be done without developing custom modules. :)

Comment: Glad to hear.Thank God it isn't otherwise we will be selling dry fruits somewhere around :p